# Finding group maxes in SQL join result

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/sql-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Two SQL tables.  One contestant has many entries:

```
Contestants     Entries
Id   Name       Id  Contestant_Id  Score
--   ----       --  -------------  -----
1    Fred       1   3              100
2    Mary       2   3              22
3    Irving     3   1              888
4    Grizelda   4   4              123
                5   1              19
                6   3              50
```

Low score wins.  Need to retrieve current best scores of all contestants ordered by score:

```
Best Entries Report
Name     Entry_Id  Score
----     --------  -----
Fred     5         19
Irving   2         22
Grizelda 4         123
```

I can certainly get this done with many queries.  My question is whether there's a way to get the result with one, efficient SQL query.  I can almost see how to do it with `GROUP BY`, but not quite.

In case it's relevant, the environment is Rails ActiveRecord and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is specific postgresql way of doing this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id) c.name, e.id, e.score
FROM Contestants c
JOIN Entries e ON c.id = e.Contestant_id
ORDER BY c.id, e.score
```

Details about `DISTINCT ON` are [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html).

My [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/23cff/2) with example.

UPD To order the results by score:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id) c.name, e.id, e.score
      FROM Contestants c
      JOIN Entries e ON c.id = e.Contestant_id
      ORDER BY c.id, e.score) t
ORDER BY score
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with the ranking functions:

```
select name, Entry_id, score
from (select e.*, c.name,
             row_number() over (partition by e.contestant_id order by score) as seqnum
      from entries e join
           contestants c
           on c.Contestant_id = c.id
     ) ec
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Not the easiest way. For this particular task (pick one record for every distinct value) postgresql has special clause - `DISTINCT ON ()`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, but something along these lines should work:

```
SELECT c.*, s.Score
FROM Contestants c
JOIN (SELECT MIN(Score) Score, Contestant_Id FROM Entries GROUP BY Contestant_Id) s
ON c.Id=s.Contestant_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

one of solutions is

```
select min(e.score),c.name,c.id from entries e
inner join contestants c on e.contestant_id = c.id
group by e.contestant_id,c.name,c.id
```

here is example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e307/27

Answer (score 1):

This simple query should do the trick..

```
Select contestants.name as name, entries.id as entry_id,  MIN(entries.score) as score
FROM entries
JOIN contestants ON contestants.id = entries.contestant_id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY score
```

this grabs the min score for each contestant and orders them ASC

Comment: This is clean, but unfortunatley PosgreSQL is requiring the GROUP BY to include the entry_id field, which makes grouping useless.